# Trying to fix Fatal error: Class 'Raveinfosys_Exporter_Helper_Data' not found in ..\app\Mage.php

Tags: magento-1.7

```
Fatal error: Class 'Raveinfosys_Exporter_Helper_Data' not found in ..\app\Mage.php on line 546.
```

I have installed new new extension Bulk Import+Export Orders to CSV in Magento 1.7, but I am getting above fatal error in admin. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have installed succesfully and i want to use it, but i am getting fatal error in admin: following error :-- Fatal error: Class 'Raveinfosys_Exporter_Helper_Data' not found in ..\app\Mage.php on line 546.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this error in this extension for quite some time when I figured out the solution (for me, at least). Disable compilation in System > Tools > Compilation. Once you disable compilation, install the extension, clear the Magento cache (I left the cache page opened in another tab to make sure I had access to it) and you should see an "Exporter" tab in the header. Hope this solves your issue because it took me many hours to find the problem.